# Получить в bash ссылку на объект Python

Tags: python, bash

У меня есть pthon скрипт
example.py

```
# !/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Script"

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
```

Как из bash скрипта инициализировать объект Foo и обратиться к его методу? Оба действия надо обязательно сделать из bash.

Comment: Ни как. Оболочка может общаться с процессом с помощью переменных окружения и параметров командной строки. Причем и то и другое только во время запуска. Ну еще можно конечно писать во всякие каналы или даже сокеты (включая tcp/ip). но во всех этих случаях все сведеться к тому, что внешний процесс должен будет по определенному api передать команду уже запущенному процессу, которую он сам обработает и сделает уже то что ему нужно в этом случае, например создаст объект

Comment: Опишите в каком контексте это нужно сдалать, может вы не верно поняли задачу.

Comment: @Hellseher, мне надо сделать так, чтобы можно было вызывать методы python скрипта shell командами в нужном мне порядке. Допустимо сделать так, чтобы объект создавался каждый раз, когда в консоли набирается команда, и вызывался соответствующий метод объекта. Если существует способ выполнять методы без создания объекта - это тоже подходит.

Comment: @Elefanobi контектст опишите. пример - *есть скрипт передаем ему параметры командной строки и он показывает, делает, читает то и то*. я у верен у вас структурная проблема, что от куда должно ввзыватся.

Comment: есть скрипт sh. передаем в него параметры, необходимые для инициализации объекта в питон(в коде параметры не показаны). Инициализируем объект питон. В терминале(в .sh) вводим параметры для методов объекта. Вызываем метод созданного объекта, передаем параметры. Метод обрабатывает. Получаем в sh ответ. Выводим в терминал.

Answer (score 2):

Напишите код с полноценной поддержкой аргументов, потом его можно обернуть в другой скрипт, например. bash/ash/fish/zsh/perl и т.д..

Для этой цели используются библиотеки для работы с аргументами командной строки

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html
- http://docopt.org/
- http://click.pocoo.org/5/

**Ссылки**

- https://realpython.com/comparing-python-command-line-parsing-libraries-argparse-docopt-click/

Comment: это хорошо, но как передать данные из питона в bash? и кроме того, как вызвать методы поочередно, используя результаты работы предыдущих?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ найден.
Код должен выглядеть так.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
set -u
userstring="get_name()" # тут должен быть input
python -c "import example; from example import Foo; m = Foo(); st = m.$userstring; print(st);"
```

Консоль
Script

Достоинства:

1. можно вводить в терминал имя метода Python вместе с позиционными
   параметрами, как это было бы в коде Python, только без ссылки на
   объект(имя или self)

Недостатки:

1. Объект надо создавать при каждом вызове
2. Вызывать методы поочередно из того же самого объекта можно только
   если нет необходимости снова делать input из bash